# How abundant could silver be in one place if given the right circumstances?

Tags: science-based, earth-like

The only limiting factors are that it has to be in an area near to the ocean and to mountains (Similar distance as the Himalayas to the Bay of Bengal), and that it has to be in a hospitable place, as there would be an entire civilization living there. It has to be abundant enough that it's considered a common metal. Meteors and godly events are a possibility too. If not silver, could it also work with another rare and silvery metal, such as platinum or palladium?

Comment: it's good practice to wait at least 24 hours before accepting an answer, if you care about getting quality answers. Few users are interested in answering a solved question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very abundant, relatively speaking.

Remember of course that [Silver is still a rare element](https://periodictable.com/Elements/047/data.html) in the universe, although it appears from what we know that there is nearly two orders of magnitude more silver in the Earth's crust (as a proportion of mass) than there is in the universe more generally. Even so, the amount is quite small by comparison to carbon or iron.

That said, the description you give of the location of silver and its accessibility is almost [a perfect description of South America](https://www.ai-journal.com/articles/10.5334/ai.1318/) just prior to the Spanish Conquistadors. Silver was quite common there, and the Andes Mountain range is not only an interesting feature that helps meet your geography request, but also a key facet to making the silver more accessible.

Mountain ranges form from deformations in the crust as a result of them shifting over the planet, and when the crust breaks or deforms in a way that creates a mountain range, it essentially pushes parts of the crust that were deep underground up to the surface. This means that most metal deposits that are found by early metallurgists are found on mountains, and active mining starts later on.

Now, making it more *relatively* common than (say) iron is going to be harder because if the distribution is fairly even then there's just going to be far more iron ore to work with but for the most part, a good mountain range is likely to bring some of the silver up from deeper underground meaning that it's possible that if you have an area with localised scarcities of iron, copper and the like, that silver will appear as relatively common in such an area. In any case, silver mining is still an important part of the South American economy, so there is at least some evidence that it can be present in sufficient quantities so as to be supposed as 'common'.